# Trying to plot f(x)= xsin(ax) and its derivatives in a single plot but graph shows nothing

Tags: plotting

The function is `f[x] := xsin(ax)`,the first derivative is `f'[x]=axcos(ax) + sin(ax)`and third derivative is `f'''[x]=-(a^3)xcos(ax) - (3a^2)sin(ax)`.I tried to plot them all in the same graph but I just get a blank graph with the axes. How do I graph them?

So far,I tried using the `Show` command to get them in a single plot but mathematica says it can't plot them together. For example, to plot them together I put `f(x), Derv1,Derv3` inside Show(). I also tried using `Manipulate` option but when I use it for `f(x),f'(x) and f'''(x)` altogether I get errors. What else can I do that works?

[image]

Comment: Did you provide a value for `a` ?

Comment: You can format inline code and code blocks by selecting the code and clicking the `{}` button above the edit window. The edit window help button `?` is useful for learning how to format your questions and answers. You may also find [this meta Q&A](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1584) helpful

Comment: I used the plot option from below after getting the first/third derivative. That's how I learnt about Manipulate option. 
For f'(x) I had these values for  {a, -8, 8} and for f'''(x) I had these {a, -518.394, 1847.46}. So did I do it all wrong from the get go?

Comment: `Clear["Global\`*"]; f[a_][x_] := x Sin[a x]; With[{a = 2}, Plot[Evaluate@{f[a][x], f[a]'[x], f[a]''[x]}, {x, 0, 2 Pi}, PlotLegends -> "Expressions"]]`

Comment: @BobHanlon I am a novice at this so this looks a bit convoluted to me. Could you give a breakdown of what you did or if possible suggest a simpler alternative?

Comment: `Clear["Global\`*"]; f[a_, x_] := x Sin[a x]; With[{a = 2}, Plot[Evaluate@{f[a, x], D[f[a, x], x], D[f[a, x], {x, 2}]}, {x, 0, 2 Pi}, PlotLegends -> "Expressions"]]`

Answer (score 2):

Here's a short version of what I think you're struggling with:

```
Clear[f, a];
f[x_] := Sin[a x];
Manipulate[
 Plot[f[x], {x, 0, 2, π}],
 {a, 1, 2}
]
```

The reason this plot is empty, is because `Manipulate` localizes the variable `a`, so the `a` in your definition of `f` is a different `a` than the one in the `Manipulate`. This happens because the line `Plot[f[x], {x, 0, 2, π}]` has no explicit reference to `a` in its unevaluated form. The best way to deal with this, is to propagate `a` as an argument so that the dependence on `a` becomes explicit:

```
Clear[f, a];
f[x_, a_] := Sin[a x];
Manipulate[
 Plot[f[x, a], {x, 0, 2 π}],
 {a, 1, 2}
]
```

Alternatively, if you absolutely must use a global variable:

```
Clear[f, a];
f[x_] := Sin[a x];
Manipulate[
  Plot[f[x], {x, 0, 2 π}],
  {a, 1, 2},
  LocalizeVariables -> False,
  TrackedSymbols :> {a}
]
```

As you can see, you need to tell the `Manipulate` to track `a`, otherwise it won't realize that the expression `Plot[f[x], {x, 0, 2 π}]` depends on `a`.